# undefined method `translate' for I18n:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, i18n-gem

On a server i had an installation of the [gollum wiki](https://github.com/gollum/gollum). It ran fine. Now I also had to install [redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) on that same server. This was a big pain, as redmine refused to run with [puma](http://puma.io/). I had to mess around a lot with different gems to make it work at all.

But for some reason i now get an error from gollum, whenever i try to create a new wiki page:

```
NoMethodError at /create/old/git-tips
undefined method `translate' for I18n:Module
```

The stack trace shows that the error occurs in this line of stringex:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/stringex-2.0.5/lib/stringex/localization/backend/i18n.rb in i18n_translations_for
        ::I18n.translate("stringex", :locale => locale, :default => {})
```

So i checked the installed packages with `gem list` and the required version of `i18n 0.6.1` is there.

Any idea, what could be wrong and how to fix this?

For reference [here's](https://gist.github.com/mikehaertl/6094165) the output of `gem list`.

Answer (score 4):

This may or may not help, but I had a similar problem on a large code base where there was an application-specific I18n module (which included some custom helper methods), but this was overriding the 't' method (a shortened form of translate).

In this case I found I could force the base-level I18n module by using two colons...

```
::I18n.t('thing')
```